# Neural Network: For Binary Classification use 1 or 2 output neurons with VGG19

Tags: deep-learning, softmax, vgg-net

I have two groups of images (concrete cracks and uncracked concrete) so they are binary classification, I am making classification for them by using vgg19.
when I used  (1) neuron for the output layer and using softmax I got accuracy 0.5 and fixed during 250 epochs, while when I used 2 neuron with softmax the accuaracy increaced above 0.9.

So, shall I have to use 1 or 2 neurons for the output for VGG19 with binary classification?